# How to store additional information about each point of a SQL Server geography line string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, spatial

I am using SQL Server 2016 and I have a Trajectory table and a TrajectoryPoint table. A trajectory consists of many trajectory points, and a trajectory point is related to only one trajectory. Each trajectory point has many values such as location, timestamp, speed, SSR code and more.

This is the current trajectory table (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trajectory](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [TimeOverFir] [time](7) NULL,
    [DistanceOverFir] [float] NULL,
    [FlightRules] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [LinkInfoId] [int] NULL,
    [StateId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CO2Emission] [float] NULL,
    [FuelConsumption] [float] NULL,
    [Flight_Id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Trajectory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is the current trajectory point table (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TrajectoryPoint](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Location] [geography] NOT NULL, --*
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Speed] [real] NULL,
    [TrajectoryId] [int] NULL,
    [SsrCode] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [TypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [SsrModeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TrajectoryPoint] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TrajectoryPoint]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TrajectoryPoint_dbo.Trajectory_TrajectoryId] FOREIGN KEY([TrajectoryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Trajectory] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TrajectoryPoint] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TrajectoryPoint_dbo.Trajectory_TrajectoryId]
GO
```

Currently, the trajectory point table has a geography column (marked with * in above code) containing the latitude, longitude and altitude of the point (that is WKT for location could be 'POINT(-122.34900 47.65100 100)').

To ease and improve calculations on the trajectory, I am considering changing the database so the trajectory has a geography of LineString containing all the points (that is WKT could be 'LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656 100, -122.343 47.656 120 )'), and remove the geography from the trajectory point.

The following code illustrates described changes for the trajectory table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trajectory](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Geography] [geography] NOT NULL, --*
    [TypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [TimeOverFir] [time](7) NULL,
    [DistanceOverFir] [float] NULL,
    [FlightRules] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [LinkInfoId] [int] NULL,
    [StateId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CO2Emission] [float] NULL,
    [FuelConsumption] [float] NULL,
    [Flight_Id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Trajectory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And for the trajectory point table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TrajectoryPoint](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Speed] [real] NULL,
    [TrajectoryId] [int] NULL,
    [SsrCode] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [TypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [SsrModeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TrajectoryPoint] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TrajectoryPoint]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TrajectoryPoint_dbo.Trajectory_TrajectoryId] FOREIGN KEY([TrajectoryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Trajectory] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TrajectoryPoint] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TrajectoryPoint_dbo.Trajectory_TrajectoryId]
GO
```

*Please note in the above code that the TrajectoryPoint.Location has been removed and the Trajectory.Geography has been added.*

A geography point can only hold information about latitude, longitude, altitude and "measure". But I need to keep much more information about each point. How can I make a "relationship" between a point in the LineString and an entry in the trajectory point table?

I am considering storing the TrajectoryPointId within the "measure" property of each point in the LineString. But I am not quite happy about this *fake* relationship. Is there any alternative or should I just stick with my current solution?

The speed value is not something I calculate but something I get from the aircraft itself via radars. There exists different categories of speed such as ground speed and true airspeed - and true airspeed is not something I am able to calculate when needed as it depends on current airmass. So I need to store this value and values like this separately. The above SQL is just simplified.

SQL Server does support m cord, and I have considered storing the timestamp in this, but I didn't want to *reserve* this space as I need a separate table for point data anyway.

I expect to have around 1.5 million trajectories a year. But I am not considerably worried about performance as the point data is something that probably will be requested for one single point at a time and not for the whole trajectory set. However, if you guys have any performance improvement ideas - *I am listening*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the points in your Geography have one common `TrajectoryId`, but each one of them has a relative position (*first* point, *second* point, ..., *nth* point).

I would consider that the **natural key** for this table is just a composite-key `(TrajectoryId, PointNr)`, where `PointNr` is just 1 for the first point of the trajectory (`LINESTRING`) 2 for the second, and so on.

That is, the idea is to **not** use a `TrajectoryPointId`, but create the table like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TrajectoryPoint]
(
    /* This is the natural key to a certain point */
    [TrajectoryId] [int] NOT NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[Trajectory] ([Id]),
    [PointNr] [int] NOT NULL,

    /* Add here all the attributes of every trajectory point */
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Speed] [real] NULL,
    [SsrCode] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [TypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [SsrModeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,

    /* And add the 2-column PRIMARY KEY */
    PRIMARY KEY ([TrajectoryId], [PointNr])
) ;
```

There is *no* need to have an identity column in every table. They tend to be convenient, but they're not always the best choice.

This assumes that your Geography is just a list of points, obviously.

---

This is a practical case:

We insert some values into the `Trajectory` and `TrajectoryPoint` tables:

```
INSERT INTO Trajectory
    (Geography, TypeId, StateId)
VALUES 
  (Geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (
     -71.8807  43.1500, 
     -71.8805  43.1497,
     -71.8803  43.1493)', 4269), 1, 1) ;

DECLARE @t AS Integer = @@IDENTITY ;

INSERT INTO TrajectoryPoint 
  (TrajectoryId, PointNr, Time, SSrModeId, SsrCode, TypeId)
VALUES 
  (@t, 1,  '2017-01-07 19:00:05', 1, 'ABCD', 0),
  (@t, 2,  '2017-01-07 19:00:15', 1, 'ABCD', 0),
  (@t, 3,  '2017-01-07 19:00:25', 1, 'ABCD', 0) ;
```

... and we would query the two tables using a somehow complicated procedure to get the points out of the LINESTRING:

```
-- We select here the trajectory we are interested in
WITH OneTrajectory AS
(
    SELECT 
        Id AS TrajectoryId, Geography AS G, G.STNumPoints() AS NrOfPoints
    FROM 
        Trajectory 
    WHERE 
        Id = @t
)

-- We get the list of Geometry Points out of the LineString in G
, GeometryPoints (TrajectoryId, PointNr, Point) AS  
( 
   SELECT T.TrajectoryId, 1, T.G.STPointN(1) 
     FROM OneTrajectory T
UNION ALL
   SELECT T.TrajectoryId, PointNr + 1, T.G.STPointN(PointNr + 1) 
     FROM OneTrajectory T, GeometryPoints GP
    WHERE PointNr < T.NrOfPoints
)

-- And we do the JOIN and retrieve whatever needed
SELECT 
    TP.TrajectoryId, TP.PointNr, GP.Point.STAsText() AS PointAsText, TP.time
FROM 
    GeometryPoints GP
    INNER JOIN TrajectoryPoint TP 
        ON TP.TrajectoryId = GP.TrajectoryId AND TP.PointNr = GP.PointNr ;
```

What you get is (slightly edited for readability)...

```
+--------------+---------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| TrajectoryId | PointNr |     PointAsText          |          time       |
+--------------+---------+--------------------------+---------------------+
|            3 |       1 | POINT (-71.8807 43.1500) | 2017-07-01 19:00:05 |
|            3 |       2 | POINT (-71.8805 43.1497) | 2017-07-01 19:00:15 |
|            3 |       3 | POINT (-71.8803 43.1493) | 2017-07-01 19:00:25 |
+--------------+---------+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

The part of the SQL for taking out the points out of the geometry was borrowed from Tom Halladay's answer to [Linestring to Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768390/linestring-to-points).

NOTE: Tested with SQL Server 2016, SP1 (13.0.4001.0)

Performance with millions of trajectories would most probably be not very good. Just the fact that you have to call one function `STPoinN` for every single point... makes it really hard. The question is: Are there (published) alternatives?

If I had to really use the information of many points at a time, I'd consider *unnormalizing* the information (via `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` triggers) and have the coordinates from points *also* in the `TrajectoryPoint` table. If it is done in a really automatic fashion, the risk of inconsistency is rather low. If the use-case doesn't require it, I'd leave it as proposed.

Comment: Never mind my previous question. I was just confused by the fact that **geography** has a `STGeomFromText` method, and that your collection is called `GeometryPoints`